# angularJS filter table as per data

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a list which look like this

```
[
    { OfficialID:1, name:'test', isActive:false },
    { OfficialID:2, name:'test4', isActive:true },
    { OfficialID:3, name:'test2', isActive:true }
]
```

> now I just want to filter and only show data when isAcitve is true,

and this is my tr of table

```
 <tr ng-repeat="d in dc.officialLeaves | filter:isActive">
     <td>{{d.OfficialID}}</td>
 </tr>
```

I think I know I want to use something like this `filter:isActive`

but what exactly should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

You can apply expression directly.

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator : anyPropertyKey}}
```

You can do something like this, This says only to compare with the field `isActive`

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{'isActive':true}">
```

Answer (score 2):

That is fine, but the filter will run quite often. For performance, you might consider filtering once in your component:

```
dc.activeOfficialLeaves = officialLeaves.filter(o => o.isActive)

 <tr ng-repeat="d in dc.activeOfficialLeaves">
     <td>{{d.OfficialID}}</td>
 </tr>
```